# Android: How to set a generated contextMenu title?

Tags: android, contextmenu, title, auto-generate

I create a context menu like this:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
>   if(v.getId() == R.id.ListView01) {
>       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_contextmenu, menu);
>   }
>   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
> }
> ```

How can I now set a generated title?

Comment: (it might be because I'm sleep deprived and therefore slow to understand but) what do you call "generated context title", do you mean the title of your app that appears in the bar of your app ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
menu.setHeaderTitle("This is my title");
```

[See ContextMenu.setHeaderTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html#setHeaderTitle(java.lang.CharSequence))